# Convert into a For Comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, stream, akka, future, for-comprehension

Testing this I can see that it works:

```
def twoHtmlFutures = Action { request =>

  val async1 = as1.index(embed = true)(request) // Future[Result]
  val async2 = as2.index(embed = true)(request) // Future[Result]

  val async1Html = async1.flatMap(x => Pagelet.readBody(x)) // Future[Html]
  val async2Html = async2.flatMap(x => Pagelet.readBody(x)) // Future[Html]

  val source1 = Source.fromFuture(async1Html) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
  val source2 = Source.fromFuture(async2Html) // Source[Html, NotUsed]

  val merged = source1.merge(source2) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
  Ok.chunked(merged)
}
```

But trying to put it into a *For Comprehension* is not working for me. This is what I tried:

```
def twoHtmlFutures2 = Action.async { request =>

  val async1 = as1.index(embed = true)(request)
  val async2 = as2.index(embed = true)(request)

  for {
    async1Res <- async1 // from Future[Result] to Result
    async2Res <- async2 // from Future[Result] to Result

    async1Html <- Pagelet.readBody(async1Res) // from Result to Html
    async2Html <- Pagelet.readBody(async2Res) // from Result to Html

  } yield {
    val source1 = single(async1Html) // from Html to Source[Html, NotUsed]
    val source2 = single(async2Html) // from Html to Source[Html, NotUsed]

    val merged = source1.merge(source2) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
    Ok.chunked(merged)
  }

}
```

But this just jumps on-screen at the same time rather than at different times (streamed) as the first example does. Any helpers out there to widen my eyelids?Thanks

Comment: Try this little change:
  for {
    async1Res <- as1.index(embed = true)(request)
    async2Res <- as2.index(embed = true)(request)
...

Comment: @mfirry unfortunately - exactly the same

Comment: What's your expected behaviour?

Comment: @mfirry Outputting each element (in this case HTML markup) onscreen when its' future completes. So with the first example that I provided _async1_ completes a few seconds before _async2_ and outputs accordingly onscreen before - this is a working example but I want to (and should be able to) do this with a _For Comprehension_

Comment: your "yield" in the for comprehension will execute after ALL your the asyncs have been executed (one after the other)

Comment: @mfirry That seems a logical reason why this isn't working. I was thinking that anything with _maps_ and _flatmaps_ could be achieved with _For Comprehensions_ but maybe not this

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris yes it can. However, a for-comp replaces a chaining of `flatMap`s, while in your original code, `flatMap`s are not chained after one another. You would have two separate for-comp, if you were to replace your `flatMap`s with them (although, since you have only one `flatMap` in each of your processings, it may not seem necessary).

Answer (score 6):

Monads are a sequencing shape and Futures models this as causal dependence (first-this-future-completes-then-that-future-completes):

```
val x = Future(something).map(_ => somethingElse) or Future(something).flatMap(_ => Future(somethingElse)
```

However, there's a little trick one can do in for comprehensions:

```
def twoHtmlFutures = Action { request =>
  Ok.chunked(
    Source.fromFutureSource(
      for { _ <- Future.unit // For Scala version <= 2.11 use Future.successful(())
        async1 = as1.index(embed = true)(request) // Future[Result]
        async2 = as2.index(embed = true)(request) // Future[Result]
        async1Html = async1.flatMap(x => Pagelet.readBody(x)) // Future[Html]
        async2Html = async2.flatMap(x => Pagelet.readBody(x)) // Future[Html]
        source1 = Source.fromFuture(async1Html) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
        source2 = Source.fromFuture(async2Html) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
       } yield source1.merge(source2) // Source[Html, NotUsed]
    )
  )
```

I describe this technique in greater detail in [this blogpost](http://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-2.html).

An alternate solution to your problem could be:

```
def twoHtmlFutures = Action { request =>
  Ok.chunked(
  Source.fromFuture(as1.index(embed = true)(request)).merge(Source.fromFuture(as2.index(embed = true)(request))).mapAsyncUnordered(2)(b => Pagelet.readBody(b))
  )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using _scala 2.11.11_ but the first example doesn't work for me with `Future.unit` or `Future.successful(())`. Also it doesn't seem to add anything (or maybe more importantly reduce code) - just puts my first example in a _for comprehension_. I like the look of your second example but it is throwing an error for me _value index is not a member of play.api.mvc.Controller_. Also nothing is being passed in the _Pagelet.readBody_ call. Also you missed a close parenthesis on the 3rd line.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere in your question that you wanted to reduce code—so I didn't offer that as an answer.  Could you elaborate what " the first example doesn't work for me with Future.unit or Future.successful(())" means? I.e. what's not working?

Comment: It's not compiling with either of those expressions. I get _value unit is not a member of object scala.concurrent.Future_ and _overloaded method value chunked with alternatives: [C](content: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[C])(implicit writeable: play.api.http.Writeable[C])play.api.mvc.Result <and>
  [C](content: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[C, _])(implicit writeable: play.api.http.Writeable[C])play.api.mvc.Result
 cannot be applied to (Any)_ or when using `Future.successful(())` I get _type mismatch; found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
 required: play.api.mvc.Result_

Comment: Thanks for the followup @jesusg_forceHarris, do you get the same problem with the current suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately still errors; all be it slightly different - _**Cannot write an instance of akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[play.twirl.api.Html,akka.NotUsed] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[play.twirl.api.Html,akka.NotUsed]]**_. Though I did have to change `fromFutureSource` to `fromFuture`. And the second expression has an error of _**value index is not a member of play.api.mvc.Controller**_ - so it doesn't seem to be able to recognise the `index` function call once `as1` and `as2` have been assigned to `as`. Bummer

Comment: You can't change from `fromFutureSource` to `fromFuture`, they do different things. As for the problem with `as` it has got to do with `as1` and `as2` not sharing a common supertype. Is that the case? (Not  evident from your example)

Comment: `as1` & `as2` are controllers and `index` is the action that I am calling in each controller which return a `Future[Result]`- so supertype - no. Also `fromFutureSource` isn't recognised as I mentioned - it runs errors and is being highlighted in red in _Intellij_ indicating that it isn't a _class_ of _Source_

Comment: So for it to work then you may either give them a common supertype with the index method signature, or ascribe a structural type for them when constructing the list. 'fromFutureSource' is a rather new method, so if you are unable to upgrade the Akka dependency you'll have to use fromFuture + flatMapConcat(identity)

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris Look at my most recent edit of the Akka Streams based solution for an alternative.

Comment: OK - I like that. `mapAsyncUnordered` seems like a really useful class. I'm wondering if I had a third _future_ then I guess I would merge that after the previous merge, i.e. `.merge(fromFuture(as3.index(embed = true)(request)))`. It is a shame that your previous edit didn't work for me (the _supertype_ issue) - it was even more concise. I'll have to look into why.

Answer (score 1):

For comprehension and `flatMap` (which is its desugared version) are used to sequence things.

In the context of `Future`, this means that in a for comprehension, each of the statement is started only once the previous one has successfully ended.

In your case, you want two `Future`s run in parallel. This is **not** what `flatMap` (or for comprehension) is.

What your code do is the following:

- do the first `index` call
- when that's over, do the second `index` call
- when that's over, do the first `readBody`
- when that's over, do the second `readBody`
- when that's over create two (synchronous) sources with the values from the two previous steps, merge them, and start returning the merged source as chunked response.

What your previous code did was

- do the first `index` call
- when that's over, do the first `readBody`
- in the meantime, do the same for the second `index` and `readBody`
- in the meantime, create a source that will output an element when the first `readBody` yields a result
- in the meantime, do the same for the second
- merge these two sources, and start all at once to give the merged output as a chunked response.

So, in this case, you start your chunked response just after receiving the request (but with nothing inside yet, waiting for the `Future`s to be resolved), while in the former case, you wait at each computation for the previous one to be over, even if you don't need its result to go on.

What you should remember, is that you should use `flatMap` on `Future`, only if you need the result from a previous computation or if you wish for another computation to be over before doing something else. The same goes for for comprehension, which is just a nice-looking way of chaining `flatMap`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your proposed `for` comprehension looks like after it's been desugared (courtesy of IntelliJ's "Desugar Scala code ..." menu option):

```
async1.flatMap((async1Res: Nothing) => 
  async2.flatMap((async2Res: Nothing) => 
    Pagelet.readBody(async1Res).flatMap((async1Html: Nothing) => 
      Pagelet.readBody(async2Res).map((async2Html: Nothing) =>
        Ok.chunked(merged)))))
```

As you can see, the nesting, and the concluding `flatMap`/`map` pair, are very different from your original code plan.

As a general rule, every `<-` in a single `for` comprehension is turned into a `flatMap()` except for the final one, which is a `map()`, and each is nested inside the previous.